# How to avoid "setState never used" when using useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

I know that if you have something like this...

```
const [state, setState] = useState('some state');
```

and you are getting the warning for setState is never used, you should simply not useState, and instead, a normal variable.

My question is, what if this is useContext instead of useState as shown below? I have this structure for other components but some components do not need to setState for this context. How can I handle this warning? Is eslint my only option here?

```
const [state, setState] = useContext(myContext);
```

I have another component that uses the setState but not the state. How would I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't destructure it if you are not going to use it:

```js
const [state] = useContext(myContext);
```

Your `useContext` (and `useState`) is returning an array. Just destructure the *things* which are in these positions:

```js
const useState = () => ["hi", "mom"];

const [position_0, position_1] = useState();


console.log(postition_0) // "hi"
console.log(postition_1) // "mom"
```

If you like to skip a variable, you could use a throwaway variable like:

```js
const [, position_1] = useState();
```

More detail [in this post](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/13-skip-values-in-destructuring/).

If you are in control of the context, however, my personal preferred option would be to return an `object` instead of an `array`, like so:

```js
const context = () => {
 ...your context here...

 return {
   state,
   setState,
   ...even more...
 }
)
```

This way, you could simply destructure only the things you need:

```js
const { state } = useContext(context); // just state
const { setState } = useContext(context); // just setState
const { state, setState } = useContext(context); // both
```

Comment: I have another component that uses the seconds element, setState but not the state. How would I handle this?

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks! const [, position_1] = useState();

Comment: Yes sorry. I didn't see the edits above. I only saw the last 3 lines. That was my mistake.